# Segmentation fault: 11, C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am able to compile the below code, but when I try and run it, I get a segmentation fault. Could someone give an example on how to debug it? I'm not sure how to use gdb to do so (I'm using a terminal, if that's relevant).

I compile it by running g++ initial.cpp, which I think should be fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<array>
#include<valarray>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

  using std::array;
  array<array<float, 1024>, 1024> grid;

  // temp grid
  array<array<float, 1024>, 1024> temp_grid;

  int size =  1024; //1024;
  float orig_val = 50.0; //50;
  float eps = 0.1;

  // initialize
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<size; j++){

      temp_grid[i][j] = 0.0;

      if(i==0 || j==0){
        grid[i][j] = 0.0;
      }
      else
      {
        // grid[i][j] = orig_val;
      }

      }
    }

  int nc = 0; // not converged
  int counter = 0; //counter

  while (nc == 0){

    // check to see if converged
    int snc = 1; // still not converged
    for (int i=1; i<size-1; i++){
      for(int j=1; j<size-1; j++){

        // calculate sur
        int sur = (grid[i+1][j] +  grid[i][j+1] +  grid[i-1][j] +  grid[i][j-1])/4.0;

        //
        if (abs(sur-grid[i][j])>eps){
          snc = 0;
        }

      }


    }

    if(snc==1){
      nc = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      // add to counter
      counter++;

      for (int i=1; i<size-1; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<size-1; j++){
          int sur = (grid[i+1][j] +  grid[i][j+1] +  grid[i-1][j] +  grid[i][j-1])/4.0;
          temp_grid[i][j] = sur;

        }
      }

      grid = temp_grid;

    }

  }

  // std::cout<<counter;

  std::cout<<grid[1][1];

  return 0;
}
```

I am able to compile the below code, but when I try and run it, I get a segmentation fault. Could someone give an example on how to debug it? I'm not sure how to use gdb to do so (I'm using a terminal, if that's relevant).

I compile it by running g++ initial.cpp, which I think should be fine.

Comment: Where do you get a segmentation fault? It's important to open your debugger and find out. If you run it in `gdb` you should get a stack trace to the point of failure.

Comment: Now is the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: At least use valgrind to give you a line number before you begin posting online: `g++ -g initial.cpp` ... `valgrind ./a.out`

Comment: Also, you seem to access uninitialized elements of `grid`, which leads to *undefined behavior*. To initialize all elements to zero just do `array<array<float, 1024>, 1024> grid = {};`

Comment: Lastly, I suggest you always build with more warnings enables, add e.g. the `-Wall` and `-Wextra` flags when building.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have enough stack space to create 8 MB of arrays.  Increase the stack size, or use `new`.